# not scrolling at the end of fragment - android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I developed an Tabs android application in which the scroll-view is not scrolling.. I am posting the code here please check and if found any error please help.. Here I used ScrollView as root and then LinearLayout... but this is not scrolling at the end (stop at half of label name:"label_h_total")

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center|top"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
>

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/arrowImageView"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_grey"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/NameTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="15dp"

    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/positionTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="15dp"

    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/IdTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_id"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

<!--items-->

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/takeoff_color"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_b"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/document"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_date"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DateTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/document_color"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_end_of"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image3"

        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/endOfTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_money"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_c"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentSalaryTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bag_color"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_h_total"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/salaryTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/purchase_order"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_g"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

XML tabs:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: remove `android:paddingBottom="10dp"`

Comment: change linear layout `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`